# Is there a way to set laptop to hibernate after being suspended for a while? (like Windows can)

Tags: laptop, suspend, hibernate

With Windows 7, my laptop was set to go to sleep after X minutes on battery, then hibernate after sleeping for X minutes. I can't seem to find a way to do that with Ubuntu Natty so I always end up with a dead laptop after a day.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this in the power settings, in the battery tab, thought it doesn't have a setting for the specific minutes as far as I can tell:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually work like I want. First of all, it won't hibernate if it's already suspended (like windows will) and even if it did, it would still be a critically low battery. Oh well, maybe in some future version they'll get this in there.